# Automatically boot into Fedora instead of Windows 8

Tags: linux, windows-8, boot, multi-boot, fedora

I have installed Fedora on a machine that has Windows 8 on it. Everything is fine except for the fact that it boots straight into Windows and I need to hit `esc` and pick Fedora if I want it to load up.

I'd prefer the machine to boot straight into Fedora, and let me choose windows if I ever need to use it.

Is Windows 8's boot manager taking precedence here? I know I need Grub to takeover but how do I go about doing that?

I guess I could reformat the machine and just install Fedora

Comment: Are the operating systems on two different disks or they share the same disk? What bootloader are you using: grub or whatever Windows uses?

Comment: Thanks Alex, they're on the same disk. I think the solution @ernie posted looks like it will lead to happiness. I'll try it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a program like [EasyBCD](https://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) to edit the boot loader and make Fedora the default system.

Comment: Thanks, I'm gonna try @ernie's command line solution first, but if I run into trouble I'll use EasyBCD.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds as if you're using the standard Windows bootloader, and you already have an option in there for your Fedora installation.  You should be able to change the default bootloader from the Windows command line.

From an admin command prompt, run `bcdedit` - this should list all the boot options.

You'll want to change the default, so something like:

bcdedit /default {linux}

{linux} will need to be the correct identifier for your linux installation.